# Struggling with what seems to me to be an indentation issue in C? I also think my maths operators are a bit off

Tags: c

So, title says it all really.

Q1. I am receiving the following when running:

"else before previous if"

Q2. My maths may be slightly dodgy.

`else if (idNUMBER < 1)`

Returns the Error: 45 is too low, id numbers can't be less than one.

Should I be using `else if (idNumber < 1 || idNumber > 100)`

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    //variables used in the program for user inputs.
    int idNUMBER;
    int milesWalked;

    //Ask user for their id number and the amount of miles that they have walked.

    printf("Please input your walker identification number and the number of miles you have walked. \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &idNUMBER, &milesWalked);

    //check if their id number is valid or if it is too high/low.
    if (idNUMBER > 99)
    {
        printf("That id number of %d is too high. id Numbers are 1 - 99.", idNUMBER);
        exit(0);
    
    } else if (idNUMBER < 1)
        ;
    {
        printf("That id number of %d is too low. id Numbers can't be less than 1.", idNUMBER);
        exit(0);
    }

    //find out what kind of walker they are, based on the values that they entered.
    if (milesWalked > 30); 
        
    {
        printf("Error: miles walked is invalid (too high)\n");
        
    }
    else if (milesWalked < 5);
    {
        printf("Error: miles walked is inavlid (too low)\n");
    }
    else if (milesWalked >= 21 && milesWalked <= 30);
    {
        printf("Walker id: %d is a serious walker.\n", idNUMBER);
    }
    else if (milesWalked >= 11 && milesWalked <= 20);
    {
        printf("Walker id: %d is a regular walkler.\n", idNUMBER);
    }
    else if (milesWalked >= 5 && milesWalked <= 10);
    {
        printf("Walker id: %d is a leisure walker\n", idNUMBER);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: remove the `;` after `if` and `else if ` statements

Comment: thanks for the reply - that wasn't the problem just something left over from a change.. the problem is really with the bottom block. Starting at //check if their id number is valid or if it is too high/low.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, I misread. Thanks a lot. I don't know why I had those there  @csavvy

Comment: To give advice about code formatting styles is dangerous. It is an area where people have fanatic religious views. But in this case for this error, my favorite style - to put the opening brackets on the same line -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Variant:_1TBS_(OTBS)  would have made the error stand out and be more visible.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is adding semi-colon after each if statement, the c compiler thinks the following

```
if( a > b);{
    printf("a is greater");
}
```

as:

```
if( a > b)
     ;  // (Here for the conditional , you have given a null statement to execute)
{
    printf("a is greater");
}
```

So Removing all the semi-colons will make the program to check all the conditions.
So if you want to execute two or more statements for a condition, then you should place the in braces after condition **without semi-colon  after the if  , and you do have placed a semicolon after IdNumber < 1 !!!**